# How to get user info in a discord embed message

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

When I want to get the user info of the user that sent the command to activate the code it returns this string:`<member 'id' of 'User' objects>` But I want it to display the discord id of the user. http://prntscr.com/ppf34x

I tried to debug it by adding the print line, this shows that discord.User.id returns that wierd bit of text. I also tried different methods that are described in the documentation. (https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#user)

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "profile":
        user = discord.User.id
        print(user)
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Profile", description="Your Profile")
        embed.add_field(name="Username:", value=f"{message.author}", inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Id:", value=f"{discord.User.id}", inline=True)
        await message.channel.send(content=None, embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at the `id` property of a specific `User` instance, not the `User` class itself.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "profile":
        user = message.author.id
        print(user)
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Profile", description="Your Profile")
        embed.add_field(name="Username:", value=f"{message.author}", inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Id:", value=f"{message.author.id}", inline=True)
        await message.channel.send(content=None, embed=embed)
```